# npm install ffi で"MSBuild.exe failed with exit code 1"のエラー

Tags: node.js, npm

**発生している問題**
Node.jsでFFIを使いたいのですが、`npm install ffi`としたときに、

```
gyp Err: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe failed with exit code: 1
```

とのエラーが表示されます。
windows build toolsはインストール済みです。

**環境**

- Node 14.15.0

**補足**

- コメントにて、Nodeのバージョン自体が対応していない可能性があるとのご指摘をいただき、`The current version is tested to run on node v0.6, v0.8, v0.9 and v0.10.`と書いてあるので、試しにv0.10に落としてみましたがやはり、

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
```

とエラーが表示されます。

Comment: こんな記述 `The current version is tested to run on node v0.6, v0.8, v0.9 and v0.10.` [ffi - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi) とか、こんなIssue [Unsupport for node 12.x #545](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/issues/545) がCloseしていないので、Node.js本体の版数が未サポートなのかもしれません。[Why does npm install ffi return error. Using node version 12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56393529/9014308)

Comment: 更に検索するとこんな記事があるようです。[Node.js と FFI の 2020-03-18 時点でのメモ; node-ffi 系 → node-ffi-napi 系](https://usagi.hatenablog.jp/entry/2020/03/18/191928), [ffi-napi - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-napi) 他にもあるらしいですが。[sbffi - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sbffi), [Yet another attempt at FFI for Node.js](https://dev.to/bengl/yet-another-attempt-at-ffi-for-node-js-4knp#enter-raw-sbffi-endraw-)

Comment: v0.10では戻りすぎでは？ 2つ目コメントの紹介記事のように`ffi-napi`の方を試してみては？ あるいはv10くらいまでのどこかの版数を試してみるとか、この辺の記事を参考にしてみるとか。[Windows10にてNode環境構築によくあるエラー](https://qiita.com/chenglin/items/b3ca0bc1dca0ed682b05), [Windowsでnpm installしてnode-gypでつまずいた時対処方法](https://qiita.com/AkihiroTakamura/items/25ba516f8ec624e66ee7)

Answer (score 1):

`ffi`のサポートはNode11で終わってしまったようです。
Node12以降では`ffi-napi`が代替といっていいようです。https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-napi
こちらを使えば、エラーは発生しませんでした。
`ffi-napi`はインストール方法も使い方も`ffi`と同じです。

**インストール方法**
windowsの場合、
管理者権限でPowershellに`npm install --global windows-build-tools`で[windows build tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools)をインストールします。
次に`npm -g install node-gyp`で[node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)をインストールします。
次に、`npm install ffi-napi`と入力します。

**使い方**
`var ffi = require('ffi-napi');`
と書く以外は`ffi`と同じです。
`ref`を使う場合は代わりに`ref-napi`が対応するので別途インストールしてください。

参考サイト: https://usagi.hatenablog.jp/entry/2020/03/18/191928